# Excuting Javascript at browser console with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, console

I want to execute a code at firefox console with selenium . I am using python . Anyone know how ?

Answer (score 2):

To execute some JavaScript in a way *similar* to what you'd do at the console, you can use the `execute_script` method. For instance, once you have your `WebDriver` instance stored in `driver`:

```
driver.execute_script("location.reload()")
```

would reload your current window. This is the same as if you'd typed `location.reload()` at the console. One difference between `execute_script` and the console is that `execute_script` executes the code inside a JavaScript function, which affects scoping. (e.g. `var foo = 1` at the console declares a *global* variable `foo`. In `execute_script` it would declare a *local* variable `foo`.)

Selenium does not provide facilities to *open* the console while Selenium is running.